# Problem with assigning 2d array as a one slice of 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pydicom, medical-imaging

I try to load series of DICOM files into 3d array. I do this on bad way because I got an error something like this (not fluent in Python):
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512) into shape (512,117).

I don't understand why, because I specify the shape as (512,512,117)

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import numpy
from pydicom import dcmread
#from pydicom.data import get_testdata_file

# fetch the path to the test data
path = 'C:/Users/tykab/Downloads/DICOM/MH DICOM + images/MH example DICOM/IMediaExport/DICOM/PAT_0000/STD_0000/SER_0003/OBJ_0001/IM_0001.dcm'
ds = dcmread(path)
root_dir = Path(ds.filename).resolve().parent
print(f'Root directory: {root_dir}\n')



files = []

for file in os.listdir(root_dir):
    files.append(file)
print(files)

data = []
s = (512,512,117)
pixel_data = numpy.zeros(s)
print (pixel_data)
for i in files:
    path_file = f'C:/Users/tykab/Downloads/DICOM/MH DICOM + images/MH example DICOM/IMediaExport/DICOM/PAT_0000/STD_0000/SER_0003/OBJ_0001/{files[0]}'
    data.append(dcmread(path_file))


for i in range(117):
    pixel_data[:][:][i] = data[i].pixel_array[:][:]

print(pixel_data)
```

Comment: `[:]` does nothing useful.  Use `pixel_data[:,:,i]`

Comment: you probably want to use a 117,512,512 array and assign a 512x12 array to the first dimension. Like: x = np.ndarray([117,512,512])  and then x[i] = pixel_array

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dimensions to 117x512x512 and assign to the first dimension like:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import numpy
from pydicom import dcmread
#from pydicom.data import get_testdata_file

# fetch the path to the test data
path = 'C:/Users/tykab/Downloads/DICOM/MH DICOM + images/MH example DICOM/IMediaExport/DICOM/PAT_0000/STD_0000/SER_0003/OBJ_0001/IM_0001.dcm'
ds = dcmread(path)
root_dir = Path(ds.filename).resolve().parent
print(f'Root directory: {root_dir}\n')



files = []

for file in os.listdir(root_dir):
    files.append(file)
print(files)

data = []
s = (117,512,512)
pixel_data = numpy.zeros(s)
print (pixel_data)
for i in files:
    path_file = f'C:/Users/tykab/Downloads/DICOM/MH DICOM + images/MH example DICOM/IMediaExport/DICOM/PAT_0000/STD_0000/SER_0003/OBJ_0001/{files[0]}'
    data.append(dcmread(path_file))


for i in range(117):
    pixel_data[i] = data[i].pixel_array

print(pixel_data)
```